# Salesforce Web-to-Lead Form Column Separation

Tags: html, leads, email-alert, code, web2lead

I'm trying to separate the following into two columns. Separation after the "phone" field. I'm using the code provided by salesforce to upload to our website. Also hoping someone can help me with email alerts when someone completes this form. I tried following other directions but I'm very inexperienced with this stuff so directions weren't very clear. Thank you!

```html
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
    <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D8Z000000thxT">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://www.blufincap.com">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
    <br>
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
    <input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
    <br>
    <label for="company">Company</label>
    <input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
    <br>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
    <br>
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
    <br>
    <label for="state">State</label>
    <input  id="00N8Z00000CIvA3" maxlength="2" name="00N8Z00000CIvA3" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
    <br>
    <label for="business_start_date">Business Start Date</label>
    <span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput">
        <input  id="00N8Z00000CJ2X4" name="00N8Z00000CJ2X4" size="12" type="text" required="required" />
    </span>
    <br>
    <label for="revenue">Annual Revenue</label>
    <input  id="revenue" name="revenue" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
    <br>
    <label for="estimate_credit_score">Estimated Credit Score</label>
    <input  id="00N8Z00000FK08d" name="00N8Z00000FK08d" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
    <br>
    <label for="requested_amount">Requested Amount</label>
    <input  id="00N8Z00000CIv8q" name="00N8Z00000CIv8q" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Was able to get it to work thanks to sfdcfox. For those in the same situation, you can also use the below to have the form auto assign a lead source:

<input id="lead_source" name="lead_source" type="hidden" value="Desired Lead Source Value" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know what you're doing, you should be handing this off to one of your web developers to corporate the appropriate changes.

Here's a very quick mock of what we can do with a couple of minor tweaks:

HTML:

```
<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
    <div class="flexArea">
        <div class="flexColumn">
            <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D8Z000000thxT">
            <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://www.blufincap.com">
            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
            <input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
            <input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="company">Company</label>
            <input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="flexColumn">
            <label for="state">State</label>
            <input  id="00N8Z00000CIvA3" maxlength="2" name="00N8Z00000CIvA3" size="20" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="business_start_date">Business Start Date</label>
            <span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput">
        <input  id="00N8Z00000CJ2X4" name="00N8Z00000CJ2X4" size="12" type="date" required="required" />
    </span>
            <label for="revenue">Annual Revenue</label>
            <input  id="revenue" name="revenue" size="20" type="number" required="required" />
            <label for="estimate_credit_score">Estimated Credit Score</label>
            <input  id="00N8Z00000FK08d" name="00N8Z00000FK08d" size="20" type="number" required="required" />
            <label for="requested_amount">Requested Amount</label>
            <input  id="00N8Z00000CIv8q" name="00N8Z00000CIv8q" size="20" type="number" required="required" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

---

CSS:

```
.flexColumn {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flexArea {
    display: flex;
}
.flexArea div {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
}
```

[image: Demo]

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/FRaCsYYHuKecGTSoCGT2/src/app.css?p=stories).

Comment: Thank you for your help! And unfortunately, we are still a pretty new startup company and can't afford to pay a web developer for the time being. Trying our best to setup our CRM in the meantime. Thanks again

Comment: @Bluefin I've been with a couple of startups, I know how that feels. Questions like this are technically off-topic ([so] is the better choice), but I'm more lenient on tangentially related questions. My time is limited, but if you have some simple questions, you can email me directly.

Comment: copy that! Was able to get it working. Thanks again!